# Custom columns with 2 links for DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have this DataTables which have a custom column with a link. It works. But after I have another link, it doesn't work. The error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at Xa (jquery.dataTables.min.js:79)
    at za (jquery.dataTables.min.js:65)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:110)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:110)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.5.1.js:381)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.5.1.js:203)
    at jQuery.fn.init.u [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.min.js:100)
    at jQuery.fn.init.k.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.min.js:184)
    at Object.success (Customers:73)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
```

For one link, the working code is

```
            $('#tbl').DataTable({
                data: result,
                columns: [
                    { data: 'id' },
                    {
                        "data": "id",
                        "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                            const a = `<a href=${webApiBaseUrl}/Customers/${oData.id}>Edit</a>`
                            $(nTd).html(a);
                        }
                    },
                ]
            });
```

For 2 links, the non-working code is:

```
            $('#tbl').DataTable({
                data: result,
                columns: [
                    { data: 'id' },
                    {
                        "data": "id",
                        "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                            const a = `<a href=${webApiBaseUrl}/Customers/${oData.id}>Edit</a>`
                            $(nTd).html(a);
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "id",
                        "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                            const a = `<a href=${webApiBaseUrl}/Customers/${oData.id}>Delete</a>`
                            $(nTd).html(a);
                        }
                    },
                ]
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function instead of `fnCreatedCell`, since that gives you a clean way to build two links for one cell.

In my simple test case, this would be as follows:

```js
$('#tbl').DataTable({
  data: result,
  columns: [
    { "data": "id" },
    {
      "data": "id",
      "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
        if (type === 'display') {
          return '<a href="' + data + 
                 '">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="' + data + 
                 '">Delete</a>';
        } else {
          return data;
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

You would need to edit my code to use your relevant URLs, of course.

The line containing `type === 'display'` is for handling [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data). In this example, it may not be strictly necessary - but it allows you to show one value in the table (your HTML string), while sorting and filtering on different values (the plain ID, with no HTML).

This creates a table with 2 columns:

[image]

And it assumes the source data is something like this:

```js
var result = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Tiger Nixon"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Airi Satou"
  }
];
```